# Perforce custom tool to select files in depot view

Tags: perforce, p4v

We have a complicated project structure in our perforce project with assets that could be under source, master, published, published_deviceType etc. directories.

All assets under the source directory have a corresponding asset under the other directories as well.

I want to create a custom tool that works in the context menu that makes it easy to navigate this structure. When I right-click on an asset, I can choose "Select in Published" or "Select in Master" and have P4V navigate to this location.

I'm familiar with creating custom tools, but not sure how to trigger a "select file" in the UI.

Is there a p4 or p4v command to do this?

Comment: I don't know of anything that will actually *select* a file in, say, P4V. Find File is excellent,and you can search for a filename throughout your entire depot. From p4, you could display all files of that name via "p4 files //depot/...myFileName*" but might be faster to go the P4V-->Search-->Find File route.